# Count all restaurants from a city by maps api

Tags: python, google-maps

i'm trying to count all restaurants in my city using python-google-places api

but is not working, i'm getting "failed with response code: INVALID_REQUEST"

What could be causing this?

My code is like that

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang
from time import sleep
YOUR_API_KEY = '<<MYKEY>>'

google_places = GooglePlaces(YOUR_API_KEY)

# You may prefer to use the text_search API, instead.
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
     lat_lng={'lat': -16.6824083, 'lng': -49.2556573}
    ,
        location='Goiania',
        radius=50000,types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT])

counter = 0;
while (query_result.has_next_page_token):
    counter = counter + len(query_result.places)


    query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
        lat_lng={'lat': -16.6824083, 'lng': -49.2556573},
        location='Goiania',
        radius=50000,types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT],
        pagetoken=query_result.next_page_token)

print(counter)
```

i'm getting this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GooglePlacesError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-9cc6675b31bc> in <module>()
     21         location='Goiania',
     22         radius=50000,types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT],
---> 23         pagetoken=query_result.next_page_token)
     24 
     25 print(counter)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleplaces\__init__.py in nearby_search(self, language, keyword, location, lat_lng, name, radius, rankby, sensor, type, types, pagetoken)
    303         url, places_response = _fetch_remote_json(
    304                 GooglePlaces.NEARBY_SEARCH_API_URL, self._request_params)
--> 305         _validate_response(url, places_response)
    306         return GooglePlacesSearchResult(self, places_response)
    307 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleplaces\__init__.py in _validate_response(url, response)
    173         error_detail = ('Request to URL %s failed with response code: %s' %
    174                         (url, response['status']))
--> 175         raise GooglePlacesError(error_detail)
    176 
    177 

GooglePlacesError: Request to URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-16.6824083%2C-49.2556573&radius=50000&type=restaurant&pagetoken=CqQCGAEAAAzE3wT0DnczXFlzyjvAaka8vRLZMlsAjF2aqezA8dtGcLIV7ePoqXAUOm0MyxgroXBcKydzt3U3rB2RFvqLijFCbJ3-ucQ-nijN1E7d4aEcC2UlKUR2gNnHfmKYmFVmfQ70lbW-UmCm79WOl2s5oQ8VYoE9bRnr01IphBbVeiS_IDBsCwmsALU4ti5z-7RSYT9ACTCgFs8bVwU9lQ2x_F3v2FtkdqP7UWl5MmNLteox4dSCwa_k3gKD9yd8mCzzos0CvS248uqn_24wLaVubPmxAUrDbSFDhoSx5c8O7S-XrHl4aZ2dx4QUznYXVcEcD_9c-AHKnPoqK-zwh2MVRiHLHNscTnxr4_iCJwsrrOcqlyQrN192HCq9BMADG1tLVxIQ16yZSa5g10FKIcHzFwQqrxoUxS_m8v1Lbr0IbujvfXRi74p71ws&language=en&key=AIzaSyD8YxHJjYdGMO-k7MbOdF807uzEYT-QGYo&sensor=false failed with response code: INVALID_REQUEST
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace?

Comment: does it succeed if you comment out `while` loop code block

Comment: Google's APIs have quotas and rate limits.  To use the `next_page_token` some delay is required.

Comment: in the first time I ran the code, there were two iterations and I got this same error, but now it does not even do an iteration,occours the same if i remove the while